# Snappydata store with hive metastore from existing spark installation

Tags: apache-spark, hive, snappydata

I am using snappydata-1.0.1 on HDP2.6.2, spark 2.1.1 and was able to connect from an external spark application. But when i enable hive support by adding hive-site.xml to spark conf, snappysession is listing the tables from hivemetastore instead of snappystore.

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("TEST APP");
JavaSparkContext javaSparkContxt = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
SparkSession sps = new SparkSession.Builder().enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate();
SnappySession snc = new SnappySession(new SparkSession(javaSparkContxt.sc()).sparkContext());
snc.sqlContext().sql("show tables").show();
```

The above code gives me list of tables in snappy store when hive-site.xml is not in sparkconf, if hive-site.xml added.. it lists me tables from hive metastore.

Is it not possible to use hive metastore and snappydata metastore in the same application?
Can is read hive table into a dataframe and snappydata table to another DF in same application?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

So, it isn't the hive metastore that is the problem. You can use Hive tables and Snappy Tables in the same application. e.g. [copy hive table into Snappy in-memory](http://snappydatainc.github.io/snappydata/howto/import_from_hive_table/#how-to-import-data-from-hive-table-into-snappydata-table). 
But, we will need to test the use of external hive metastore configured in hive-site.xml. Perhaps a bug.

You should try using the Snappy smart connector. i.e. Run your Spark using the Spark distribution in HDP and connect to Snappydata cluster using the connector (see docs). Here it looks like you are trying to run your Spark app using the Snappydata distribution.

Comment: i am using HDP Spark distribution and connecting to snappydata using smart connector. looks like a bug for me. I have followed the docs from snappydata and it works as expected without hive-site.xml